# How can achieve loose coupling 'Service Oriented Architecture' (SOA)? Explain using a suitable solution

Tags: web-services, soa, loose-coupling

An IT architecture composed of software that has been exposed as “Services” – i.e. invoked on-demand using a standard communication protocol. So, loose coupling on how to use SOA, give a good example.

Answer (score 1):

There are three major types or methods or approaches that have been emerging for club information, disparate and systems in a business. As different service providers and businesses race towards providing solutions to customers and consumers, these approaches help to meet the requirements for coarse-grained, loosely clubbed and asynchronous services.

**1.   The Enterprise Service Bus**

The first approach that helps to build and implement an optimal SOA is the enterprise service bus or ESB. This approach helps to coordinate and arrange the different elements that are in the form of distributed services on a network. This approach considers the systems to be discrete and distributed services that connect to one another through message oriented infrastructure that is asynchronous. This kind of a message-oriented infrastructure makes it possible to have loosely coupled connections between independent services or modules.

**2.   Business Process Management**

Many companies, for many years now, have tried to solve business process problems by the implementation of Business Process Management approach. This approach takes into consideration the IT assets and systems as activities or tasks that participate in well synchronized and well-orchestrated business procedures.   BPM tools are mainly used at the time of modeling and designing procedures rather than using them to construct processes that can reach integration objectives. This is the main challenge of BPM. By BPM solutions on their own are enough to meet SOA requirements because they do not consist of the runtime environment that is needed for loosely coupled modules.

**3.   Service Oriented Integration**

The third and the last approach to proper implementation of SOA is the service-oriented integration approach. This particular approach makes use of the architectural guiding rules or principles to build an environment or ecosystem of services that businesses can combine dynamically and create superior level processes that can meet ever changing and evolving requirements. This approach moves past tightly coupled and brittle modules by creating a distinction between the consumer and producer of a service. It thus imposes the aspect of loose coupling that is needed to implement SOA properly to meet business requirements. Even this approach by itself isn’t sufficient to guarantee long time running interactions between services.